# Trying to understand Hilbert Spaces...

Tags: hilbert-spaces, definition

I am trying to get a hold on Hilbert Spaces, but I am having difficulties combinging various definitions.

I have looked it up on wikipedia and wolfram, there it states something like "A Hilbert space $H$ is a real or complex inner product space that is also a complete metric space with respect to the distance function induced by the inner product.".

In Croom's *Principles of Topology* it says *"Hilbert space $H$ consists of all infinite sequences $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots )$ for which each coordinate $x_i$ is a real number and for which the sum of all $x_{i}^{2}$ converges to a finite limit $\dots$*

(Im a little confused) Simply put... What is a Hilbert Space?

I am trying to get a *Topologists point of view* on the matter. I read that $H$ has some useful properties that come in handy when proving some theorema, so..

Comment: Croom talks about $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$, a Hilbert space indeed, but not the general definition. It is true, nevertheless that every infinite-dimensional separable real Hilbert space is isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @julien. Aha, so a Hilbert space need not to be infinite? How can i get more info on $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{R})$? What is this space called?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space

Comment: @omar No, it need not be infinite-dimensional, $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ are Hilbert spaces. As you can see in user18921's comment, $\ell^2$ is called a sequence space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you understand the concept of a linear (vector) space?

If so, then think of equipping the space with an *inner product* $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ 
which you can think of as a device for measuring angles in this space.

Now, that inner product induces a *norm* (given by $\|x\|=\langle x,x\rangle^{1/2}$) and this gives us a device for measuring length in this space.

Finally, suppose the space has the property that it is *complete* in the norm above, i.e. every Cauchy sequence in the space (again where distance is measured in terms of $\|\cdot\|$) has a limit which is *in the space*.

If all of the above is satisfied, then we say the space is a *Hilbert space*.

In summary, a Hilbert space is a normed, linear space with an inner product which is complete in the norm induced by the inner product.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$). This can be made into an [inner product space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) by specifying an inner product $\langle*,*\rangle,$ which takes two vectors and returns an element of $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$). Finally, a [Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) is a particularly nice kind of inner product space. Technically, a Hilbert Space is an inner product space that is complete with respect to the norm $ \|x\| = \langle x,x\rangle^{1/2}$. This just means it needs to be complete with respect to the metric $d(x,y) = \langle x-y,x-y\rangle^{1/2}$. Note that we have defined the metric such that $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|.$

I don't know the details about the useful properties of Hilbert space, but broadly speaking, everyone agrees that Hilbert Space is the best. Everyone loves Hilbert space.